# How to rename a file system /dev/sda1 to new_name through command prompt?

Tags: boot, command-line, grub2, partitioning, mount

I want to change the name of my file system which is now `/dev/sda1` to `/new_filename` through the command prompt properly.

I tried a lot of tools like `umount`, `fstab` likewise many others too, but not able to perform and reach to that level.

Comment: Can you explain **why** you want to rename this folder? Because it's one of most important directories, any wrong manipulation would totally kill your computer, even the BIOS would be affected

Comment: Please update your question with the exact mount command and /etc/fstab lines you have tried, and their outcome.

Comment: `/dev/sda1` isn't the name of a filesystem - it's the name of the block device on which the filesystem resides. You should be able to change the filesystem **label** with the appropriate filesystem-specific tool (ex. `tune2fs` for ext2/3/4 filesystems).